# Informix - Count and make pagination at same time

Tags: pagination, informix

Currently I´m doing this (get pagination and count), in Informix:

```
select a.*, b.total from (select skip 0 first 10 * from TABLE) a,(select count(*) total from TABLE) b
```

The problem is that I´m repeating the same pattern - I get the first ten results from all and then I count all the results.

I want to make something like this:

```
select *, count(*) from TABLE:
```

so I can make my query much faster. It is possible?

Comment: Am I interpreting your use of the keyword TABLE correctly if I assume that within your question, it should be regarded as a surrogate for some specific table in your database, rather than as a keyword?  Why do you want the total count with each row?  What's the repetition?  You can provide placeholders for the SKIP and FIRST values AFAIK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119463/better-way-for-getting-total-count-along-with-paging-in-sql-server-2012