# Spring JDBC Template Not Binding all parameters (Fetch Parameter value)

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate, oracle12c

I was learning new feature of Oracle 12 C (Top-N Queries and Pagination). I tried few examples with offset and fetch keywords and it worked well when i use sql developer. I tried implementing the same with Spring jdbcTemplate and I see a strange behavior.
Ex: Here is the code snippet:

```
// get first ten entities
String query = "SELECT * FROM ENTITY E order by E.ID offset ? rows fetch next ? rows only";
SqlRowSet rowSet = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(query, 1, 10);
while(rowSet.next()){
  //do something
}
```

Spring throws following exception:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM ENTITY E
>   order by E.ID offset ? rows fetch next ? rows only]; nested exception
>   is : ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"

I tried few things same on postgres database but no luck, finally i thought of removing parameters and it worked when i remove third parameter and set a hard coded value in query string.ex:

```
"SELECT * FROM ENTITY E order by E.ID offset ? rows fetch next 10 rows only"
```

Is it not allowed to use bind parameter in fetch clause?

Comment: Will not be possible to parameterize via java but can be accomplished via stored procedure. Follow the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352471/getting-total-row-count-from-offset-fetch-next

Comment: have you tryed to use named parameters?

Comment: @mhasan: where does the question you mentioned state that it is not possible to use parameters in the fetch next term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add () on the fetch parameter, it works fine:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM ENTITY E order by E.ID offset ? rows fetch next (?) rows only";
```